# Invoke AWS lambda from Eclipse: InvalidRequestContentException

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I was following the tutorial here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/lambda-tutorial.html#lambda-tutorial-invoke-function
I right clicked on my editor, chose AWS Lambda -> Run function on AWS Lambda, and then in the input box, I've tried the following but none of them worked.

```
test
"test"
{"test", "value"}
```

And I got this exception:

```
==================== INVOCATION ERROR ====================
com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvalidRequestContentException: Could not parse request body into json: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x80
 at [Source: [B@7c56c329; line: 1, column: 3] (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestContentException; Request ID: 9ecedb86-3310-11e8-9f00-4798fcb419ad)
```

Can anyone help? What's wrong with my input? Is there something else that is wrong but was not indicated by the error message?

If I try `{"key": "value"}`, I got

```
An error occurred during JSON parsing: java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred during JSON parsing
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@4501b7af; line: 1, column: 1]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@4501b7af; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:857)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:62)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1511)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1102)
```

Basically couldn't get it work if input type is a String..... Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why, but it started working with `"test"` now...

Answer (score 2):

it's supposed to be a json string Try:

```
{"key": "value"}
```

Comment: Well, the tutorial does "AWS Lambda" and I watched a video also does "aString", but this is a good point and I will try. Also if we serialize a string into json string, it should be { "string" }

Comment: @JiechaoWang not sure what you're using to serialize, but `{ "string" }` is not a valid json text. If tuturial/video are asking you to put something else than json as input, they are wrong.

Comment: I use Gson. So string is an object in Java. If you serialize a string object into json string, what would be the output? At least Gson gives me "aString", although "aString" is not in a json format

Answer (score 0):

This **worked** for me. Try to use \ so that it could be able to parse the JSON.
I worked in POWERSHELL platform

```
 aws lambda invoke --function-name new-function --invocation-type RequestResponse --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '{ \"name\":\"new_value\"}' output.json
```